# HTMLPurifier causes a 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, htmlpurifier

I have setup `HTMLPurifer` using the default configuration found [here](http://htmlpurifier.org/docs#toclink0)

All seems to be working ok apart from when I pass text containing something like `<script></script>`. Instead of filtering this out as an `XSS` attack, I receive an *internal server error*.

I've tried other html like `<b></b>` and this works ok, so It must be something to do with the script tag specifically. Any idea? Thanks.

Edit: Ok so I've tried all kinds of things to enable error logging. I've deliberately creating PHP errors to test that errors are being written to the log and this is ok. However no matter what I do I can't get the 500 error to log its cause.

Comment: What error message is reported in the server's error log?

Comment: And if you don't have access to your server error log, temporarily turn on display errors:  `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: I've searched the error_log and I can't find any entries for this occurrence. I actually have the code you suggested in my app at the moment but it doesn't seem to help as I'm redirected to the 500 error page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My psychic debugging skills tell me you should turn off mod_security.

Comment: Genius! mod_security was the problem. Added a rule to allow this to go through. Thanks